# Not getting public profile URL from calling LinkedIn API Oauth version 2.0

Tags: android, linkedin-api

Previously I was using LinkedIn Oauth API 1.0 for getting public profile URL. But now Linkedin has deprecated 1.0 version, hence I moved to Outh API 2.0 (latest), but I am not getting the public profile URL from latest API 2.0 version.

I have used https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me to get user details. By calling this I am only getting first name, last name, profile picture,but not getting public profile URL in response. i need public profile URL from LinkedIn API.

Please advice what I need to do!

Comment: I am unsure about the `scope` you are using in your configuration settings but in general terms, the new `r_liteprofile scope` does not support the public profile URL. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/lite-profile) for more info on this.

Comment: Yes, I have checked this,but as per my requirement I need public profile URL. Is there any scope available for this? OR What should I need to do If I want it in my response?

Comment: Answer updated as for below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unsure about the `scope` you are using in your configuration settings but in general terms, the new `r_liteprofile scope` does not support the public profile URL. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/lite-profile) for more info.

UPDATE: 
If the public profile URL is required, then you need to look into the `r_basicprofile` scope. For the `r_basicprofile` fields available to you, see [this link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/basic-profile) and [this link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api#public-profile-url).

**Note** also, as for my previous answer in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56476556/how-to-apply-for-a-linkedin-api-permissions-in-2019), that you need to apply for Linkedin permission through the marketing developer platform link. You will be asked to fill up a survey that is just one page in order to submit your request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @rags2riches, This is very helpful. I have an question regarding the scope. currently My linkedIn app have "r_emailaddress, r_liteprofile, w_member_social" permission. How can I got "r_basicprofile" permission for my LinkedIn App. Do I need to apply somewhere in LinkedIn for get this permission?

Comment: Hi, links are included in my answer. Do you need anything else to accept the answer as valid and helpful?

Comment: Hi, As per your suggestion and refer like I have requested for "Linkedin Marketing developer" and also filled out the survey and sent to Linkedin, 15 days passed but I haven't get any update on it . It is still  "Review in progress". I have also sent them email to know the status but they didn't replied. can please suggest me, what I need to do? Is there any way to contact to them.

Comment: Did you get a reply from LI by now?

Comment: They declined the application without providing any reasons. In the end, we decided to ditch them in order to use a different solution.