# How to apply for a LinkedIn API permissions in 2019

Tags: linkedin-api

I've tried googling and going through LinkedIn/Microsoft developer documentation a few times over, however it is still unclear how one can apply for elevated API permissions (`r_fullprofile`) for an app or even contact LinkedIn customer support.

We already have an app set up and authentication/basic API access working just fine. It is still not clear however what the application process is nowadays and how to contact them. The partner program pages are no longer there, all the contact us links are gone from the site as well, and their docs and support forums are no help either.

I would appreciate any help or advice on how to proceed with this.

UPDATE: Just to clarify, we do have API v2 and Oauth working already. We need to know what's the application procedure to get the `r_fullprofile` permission and where can we apply.

Comment: try these links first: [link](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2018/redirecting-oauth-uas) and [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq). I hope this helps and if you need additional support please share your code and/or some error logs to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @rags2riches apologies, I wasn't quite clear in my original post, we need an elevated permission called `r_fullprofile`. There is no information anywhere how to get one or where to apply for this permission, as there is no clear way to contact inkedIn on this issue. I updated my original post to clarify this.

Comment: The `r_fullprofile` should be available [here](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products) under the marketing developer platform link. You will be asked to fill up a survey as I did a couple of days ago. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `r_fullprofile` should be available [here](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/products) under the marketing developer platform link. You will be asked to fill up a survey as I did a couple of days ago. Hope this helps.

Comment: LinkedIn never reviews any applications to Marketing Developer Platform though. How long did you have to wait for the review process? We've been waiting for 3 months now, and no feedback from the LinkedIn team..

Comment: @rags2riches did LinkedIn get back to you on the approval? Been 90 days for me as well.

Comment: r_fullprofile is NOT available under marketing developer platform

Answer (score 2):

I applied on 20 May and I'm still waiting for "Marketing Developer Platform" permission review.
Please, Could someone tell me how long it takes to get permissions approval?

Comment: I am not sure about the "Marketing Developer Platform", but I've been advised by LinkedIn support that the permission can also be obtain via the "LinkedIn Talent Solutions Program". You can apply for it here: https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR9NGaraHZBFMnmu44oLEKp1UNEFBVU9YSFJFUE03RUU3UFU4MEJXRVRLRi4u

Comment: Did this go ok? How long did it take?